# Prove $\text{rank}(AXB)=\text{rank}(X)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Let $A \in Mat_{mxm}$ and  $B \in Mat_{nxn}$ be invertible matrices and $X \in Mat_{mxn}$ a matrix.

Prove $\text{rank}(AXB)=\text{rank}(X)$

So I proved $\text{rank}(AX)=\text{rank}(X)$ using the nullity spaces of $AX$ and $X$, but got stuck.

Any help or hints appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the fact that $rank(XB)=rank(X)$?

Comment: @Giulio Why is that true?

Comment: I proved it in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining your knowledge with
$$
\operatorname{rank}(X) = \operatorname{rank}(X^T)
$$
and
$$
\operatorname{rank}(XB) = \operatorname{rank}(B^TX^T)
$$
gives the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Let's prove that $\mathrm {rank}(BX)=\mathrm {rank}(X)$, knowing that $B$ is invertible.

**Proof**: Let $V$ be a matrix such that $B^TX^TV=0$. Multiply both sides by $(B^T)^{-1}\implies X^TV=0$. This tells us that $X^T$ shares the same nullspace as $B^TX^T$ which implies $\mathrm {rank}(X)=\mathrm {rank}(X^T)=\mathrm {rank}(B^TX^T)=\mathrm {rank}((XB)^T)=\mathrm {rank}(XB)$, knowing the fact that $\mathrm {rank}(C)=\mathrm {rank}(C^T)$ for a matrix $C$.

---

So now we know that $\mathrm {rank}(XB)=\mathrm {rank}(X)$ and $A$ is invertible, which gives us $$\mathrm {rank}(AXB)=\mathrm {rank}(A(XB))=\mathrm {rank}(XB)=\mathrm {rank}(X)$$
where the second equality comes under the hypothesis $A$ invertible.

Comment: Could you please explain why the second equality in the last row is right? I know you proved $\text{rank}(AX)=\text{rank}(X)$, but why can we place $X$ instead of $AX$ in the rank?

Comment: The passage was different, I changed it and explained. There I used the hypothesis that $B$ was invertible, hope now it's clear!

Comment: It is. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

It is known that:
$$
rank(XY) \le min(rank(X), rank(Y))
$$

Suppose that $Y=AXB$, then $X=A^{-1}YB^{-1}$.

$$
rank(Y)=rank(AXB) \le min(rank(A), rank(X), rank(B))=rank (B)
$$
$$
rank(X) = rank(A^{-1} X B^{-1}) \le   min(rank(A^{-1}), rank(B), rank(Y^{-1}))=rank(B)
$$

$rank(Y) \le rank(X), \space rank(X) \le rank (Y) \Rightarrow rank(X)=rank(Y)$

**P.S.**
You may notice that there is a little gap in my proof. Here I'll briefly explain what just happended:
$$
rank(AXB) \le min (rank(AX), rank(B)), \\
rank(AX) \le min(rank(A), rank(X)) \\
$$
And here we got:
$$
rank(AXB) \le min(rank(AX), rank(B) ) \le \\
\le min(min(rank(A), rank(X)), rank(B)) \le \\
\le min(rank(A), rank(X), rank(B))
$$